# Using setMaxResults() didn't solve OutOfMemoryError while fetching data

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g, lazy-loading, hibernate-criteria

Although I have read couple of articles and questions posted here, I still can't figure out how `criteria.setMaxResults()` actually works and why it didn't solve my problem.

Database I'm using is Oracle10g. The code below is used for lazy load paging and it needs to fetch 15 rows per page, so `pageSize = 15` and `index` depends on which page are you on. For the first page it is `0`. Total number of rows in table is 60k.

```
public List<FormObject> fetchFormByParams(FormObjectParameters parameters, int pageSize, int index) {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = criteriaFromParameters(false, parameters, session);

    if (pageSize > 0) {
        criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        criteria.setFirstResult(index);
    } else {
        criteria.setMaxResults(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        criteria.setFirstResult(0);
    }

    List<FormObject> result = (List<FormObject>) criteria.list(); //line 163
    return result;
}
```

When line 163 is executed, it takes 30-45 seconds until application returns 15 rows and sometimes it throws `OutOfMemoryError`. Also, when it was less data in DB (less then 100) then the application returns 15 rows in couple of seconds. Don't know why this is happening if I'm using lazy load and `setMaxResults()`.

I also tried with `setFetchSize()` but that didn't work for me and it returned all the rows from DB since it didn't use `ROWNUM`. Maybe it's something about the driver I'm using, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to change it.

Comment: Can you show the entities involved in the query and their mappings? Also, you could tell Hibernate to show the sql's that are running... You can get some tips there...

Comment: Was it an OutOfMemoryError : heap space ? In this case, when you encounter an oom (of the heap), the way to proceed is to configure the JVM to dump memory (startup parameter : -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError), open the dump in an analyzer tool (for example : eclipse memory analyzer tool), and start looking for what is causing the memory consumption to be so high (with 15 rows displayed, could it be some huge clobs ?, lots of EAGER @OneToMany or ManyToMany relations ?)

Comment: @PauloHenrique - unfortunately I'm not allowed to post actual code.

Comment: @Thierry - there is around 20 ManyToOne and one EAGER, so I'm aware that complexity of the entity could be the issue. But on the other hand when there was only around 100 rows in DB, fetching of 15 rows was done in couple of seconds.

Comment: ManyToOne relations are eager by default. each of these 20 relations could trigger more loading via ManyToOne or EAGER OneToMany. Any way, to find the culprit, analyze a heap dump once an oom occurs, to see what are the entities that use up all the memory. Chances are that you are not displaying gigabytes of info on one page, so making the relation lazy could fix your issue, without loosing functionnality

Comment: I'll try. Thank you for advice.

Comment: I know that I am going way off topic. But I am using `Solr` to index data. I have 7500 (and growing) records in my database. I have average search time of 1.4 seconds. ;)